# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named... importing from a sub-sub directory

Tags: python, import, module, subdirectory

I'm unable to import modules from a subfolder which imports a module from a sub-sub folder. I'm using python 3.6.

The structure of the folders look like this:

```
src
├── script.py
└── prepare_data
          ├── __init__.py
          ├── test.py      
          └── lib
               ├── aspect_extraction.py
               └── __init__.py
```

And in `aspect_extraction.py` I do:

```
def aspect_extraction():
    print("ok this worked")
```

`test.py` looks like this:

```
from lib.aspect_extraction import aspect_extraction
def test_func():
    aspect_extraction()

test_func()
```

`script.py` looks like this:

```
from prepare_data.test import test_func
test_func()
```

When I run `pipenv run python src/script.py`

```
File "/src/prepare_data/test.py", line 1, in <module>
from lib.aspect_extraction import aspect_extraction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

Weirdly, when I run `pipenv run python src/prepare_data/test.py`, it works.

```
ok this worked
```

I cannot identify what the problem is... Is this related to python version?

Comment: Can you try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to src folder and try and run the command `pipenv run python src/script.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import statement in test.py looks for lib.aspect_extraction in the current working dir, the one from where it was call (usually the one where script.py is, but not necesarily). Simplest solution (not the best): change the import statment:

```
from prepare_data.lib.aspect_extraction import aspect_extraction
def test_func():
    aspect_extraction()

test_func()
```

You can check the current working dir with os.getcwd(). That's your first reference for imports.

Also you can get the runing python file with os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)). Insert these lines in script.py and test.py to check the difference:

```
import os
WORK_DIR = os.getcwd()
THIS_FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('WORK_DIR', WORK_DIR)
print('THIS_FILE_DIR', THIS_FILE_DIR)
```

Information about where python looks for modules:

> "The first thing Python will do is look up the module in
>   sys.modules. This is a cache of all modules that have been previously
>   imported.
>
> If the name isn’t found in the module cache, Python will proceed to
>   search through a list of built-in modules. These are modules that come
>   pre-installed with Python and can be found in the Python Standard
>   Library. If the name still isn’t found in the built-in modules, Python
>   then searches for it in a list of directories defined by sys.path.
>   This list usually includes the current directory, which is searched
>   first."

More in https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Hope this helps.

Comment: An explicit relative import would also work in `test.py`: `from .lib.aspect_extraction import aspect_extraction` (note the leading dot before `lib`). See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for details.

Comment: `from prepare_data.lib.aspect_extraction` worked. Thank you!